# How to specify timestamp in sqoop import from MySQL to HBase?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, timestamp, hbase, sqoop

I wanted to import the structured data from my MySQL database sqoopDB using sqoop, but I met some pbs when I tried to specify the **timestamp** mapping. For example,

```
$ sqoop import \
  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoopDB \
  --username root -P \
  --table sensor \
  --columns "name, type, value" \
  --hbase-table sqoopDB \
  --column-family sensor \
  --hbase-row-key id -m 1
Enter password:
...
```

Can I add another parameter `--timestamp` to specify the **timestamp** mapping ? Such as

```
--timestamp=insert_date_long
```